# Django model and views to summarize and plot an uploaded CSV

Tags: python, django

I have a simple web application where a user uploads a CSV of some dataset and some summary statistics and box plots are displayed. I heard that it is better to have so called skinny views and fat models, though I'm unsure how is best to divide the work. How could I improve my database schema and division of labour?

## views.py

```
class HomeView(View):
    """View that handles when users land on the homepage"""

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'summary/home.html')

    # Will currently raise an HttpResponseNotAllowed if POST request received to home

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UploadView(TemplateView):
    """Users land here after successfully signing in and are prompted to upload a CSV file"""
    form_class = UploadFileForm
    template_name = 'summary/uploads.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        datasets = Dataset.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {
            'datasets': datasets,
            'csv_form': form,
            'within_dataset_limit': request.user.within_dataset_limit()
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)

    def post(self, request): 
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['dataset_file']
            datasets = Dataset.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            context = {
                'datasets': datasets,
                'csv_form': form,
                'within_dataset_limit': request.user.within_dataset_limit(),
            }
            # Check the file is a CSV
            if not str(uploaded_file).lower().endswith('.csv'):
                context['error'] = 'File not in CSV format.'
                return render(request, 'summary/uploads.html', context)
            # Check the file size is within the set limit
            elif not 0 < uploaded_file.size < request.user.max_dataset_size:
                context['error'] = 'File exceeds size limit.'
                return render(request, 'summary/uploads.html', context)
            else:          
                ds = Dataset(user=request.user, dataset_name=str(uploaded_file), dataset_file=uploaded_file)
                ds.save()
                return redirect(f'/{request.user.pk}/{ds.id}/overview/') 

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class OverviewView(TemplateView):
    """Display head and summary statistics of the uploaded dataset"""
    template_name = 'summary/overview.html'

    def get(self, request, upk, dpk):
        if request.user.pk == upk:
            ds = Dataset.objects.get(pk=dpk)
            head, summary, df = dataset_stats(ds)
            request.session['dataframe'] = df.to_json()
            context = {
                'first_five': head,
                'summary_stats': summary,
            }
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)

def delete_dataset(request, upk, dpk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.pk == upk:
            try:
                ds = Dataset.objects.get(pk=dpk)
                os.remove(ds.dataset_file.path)
                ds.delete()
                return HttpResponse(status=200)
            except Dataset.DoesNotExist:
                return HttpResponseNotFound()
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()

def boxplot(request):
    """Generation of boxplots to be moved to computation server"""
    # Get the selected columns from the overview view
    selected_columns = request.GET['selectedColumns']
    selected_columns = json.loads(selected_columns)
    code, boxplot_html = generate_plots(selected_columns, request.session.get('dataframe'))
    if boxplot_html is not None:
        return HttpResponse(status=code, content=boxplot_html)
    else:
        error = "Could not create your plots"
        return HttpResponse(status=code, content=error)
```

## models.py

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return "user_{}/{}".format(instance.user.pk, filename)

class Dataset(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    dataset_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    dataset_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dataset_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=self.user)
        if user.num_datasets == user.max_datasets:
            return # Exceeding the max number of datasets
        else:
            user.num_datasets += 1
            user.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=self.user)
        user.num_datasets -= 1
        user.save()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```